# Is it true Mars once had life? (like Earth)

Tags: solar-system, biology, solar-system-exploration, nasa

Nasa had proven Mars once had water and still has under ground. So dose that mean mars once had life or maybe still has?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean anything other than that Mars had large amounts of flowing water billions of years ago, but that's not a physics question to begin with, but a general science and logic question.

Comment: How can anyone answer this? It will be answered when some future Mars mission finds incontrovertible evidence of life, and not until then.

Comment: OK, seriously:  existence of water is pretty much required for all Terran lifeforms,  but 1) existence is not sufficient, just necessary,  2) there could well be life forms which are not water-based.

Comment: What is your definition of life?

Comment: @JohnRennie: You have answered it the only way that an honest scientist will answer these kinds of questions. Sadly that leaves a lot of folks at NASA outside of the "honest scientist" category these days.

Comment: Is this really a question of physics, anyway ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics.

Comment: Also, NASA is an acronym for [National Aeronautics and Space Administration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA) and is not a *word* ("Nasa") that some Brits would have you believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As yet unknown - there are some hints that life might exist ie [methane emissions](http://www.space.com/29674-mars-meteorites-methane-life-search.html), but no proof.

Comment: The methane measurements seem rather shaky. As of now I wouldn't even bet a cup of Pete's Coffee on them.

Comment: Why don't they just go to where water is flowing, scoop up some sub-surface mud and put it under a microscope? Is it really that difficult for the next Mars lander?

Comment: I suspect for the same reason that one can probably grab a microscope, go to the Atacama, dig up a scoop of dirt and come away with the conclusion that this planet never had life... and with fossils one really has to hit the right layer or there is absolutely nothing. Honestly, if Mars once looked like the place where I grew up, they would have seen fossilized shells from ten feet away.. but they haven't... and that's not surprising. The easy to see stuff is maybe 500 million years old and by that time Mars was dry.

Comment: @CuriousOne  How about a cup of **Peet's** coffee?  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I suspect that soon they could insert a microscope into my skull without finding a single neuron... :-)

Comment: AFAIK they have only looked at sandstone or similar, or alternatively volcanic flows. Neither of which are conducive to fossils. Have they put *anything* under a microscope?